# Remplir les blancs dans des paroles de chansons difficiles à comprendre ?

Tags: discussion, scope

J’écoute beaucoup de chansons pour améliorer mon français. J’ai besoin des paroles de ces chansons, puisque je ne peux pas tout comprendre à l’oreille. Malheureusement, il n’y a pas toujours de bonnes ressources sur la toile. Il arrive parfois que les seules paroles disponibles aient des défauts.  C’est-à-dire que même des locuteurs natifs ont parfois du mal à comprendre certains mots d’une chanson, et ne donnent que des paroles incomplètes.

**Alors peut-on utiliser *French Language* pour remplir les blancs dans les paroles d’une chanson ?**

Moi, je sais qu’on peut poser n’importe quelle question pourvu que le but soit de comprendre le français à l’écrit, et que ce soit faisable de répondre en quelques phrases. Je dirais qu’on peut également utiliser ce site pour disséquer des propos parlés, si la matière requise pour les écouter se trouve à la portée de chacun qui lit la question. S’il s’agit de quelques mots mal prononcés, j’ai des doutes.

En outre, les chansons sont un bon moyen pour apprendre une langue. Elles m’aident à m’accoutumer à la grammaire, et elles sont un bon soutien pour me rappeler le genre des noms communs. Une petite partie d'un chant peut faire revenir la plupart d’un texte. C’est pourquoi je suis également enclin à penser qu'il serait sage d'autoriser ces questions.

J’espère que vous pouvez m’expliquer à quel point de telles questions sont souhaitables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oui, pour des chansons ou autres (par exemple des films), mais à trois conditions :

1. D'abord, chercher les paroles de la chanson sur Internet. Ne demander ici que si les paroles sont introuvables.
2. La question doit impérativement pouvoir être trouvée par quelqu'un qui se poserait la même question. Il faut donc avoir une référence précise, telle que « la troisième strophe de la chanson [titre] de [auteur] » ou « dans le film [titre] de [réalisateur], à XXmin YYs, lorsque [personnage] répond à [personnage] ». Une question qui ne fournirait qu'un extrait sonore non identifié ne serait pas acceptable car non trouvable.
3. Il serait préférable de fournir également un extrait sonore avec la phrase problématique et un peu de contexte avant. Ce n'est pas strictement indispensable, mais ça augmente beaucoup la probabilité que quelqu'un pourra répondre.

Comment: Oui, et vu le volume de ce qui est disponible sur le web, il risque d'y avoir extrêmement peu de candidats qui passent la phase 1.